# Apache Lucene 5.0.1 FuzzyQuery Search Issue

Tags: java, apache, lucene, fuzzy-search

I'm having issues implementing the FuzzyQuery search within Apache Lucene 5.0.1.

I'm able to implement a regular case-sensitive query (using a modified StandardAnalyzer) that reads through a text file containing various words and returns the number of matches/hits compared to a hard-coded string. I am unable to apply this to a FuzzyQuery. Here is the program, it is assumed you have the Lucene Package/Library imported:

```
public class FuzzyMatcherTest {

private final static String indexPath = "C:"+File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"username"+File.separator+"Documents"+File.separator+"ComparisonDocs";
private final static String filePath1 = "C:"+File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"username"+File.separator+"Documents"+File.separator+"ComparisonDocs"+File.separator+"test.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException, ParseException {

    System.out.println("Your Stuff:");
    createIndex();
    searchIndex("Test");
    cleanDirectory();

    }

public static void createIndex() throws CorruptIndexException, LockObtainFailedException, IOException {
    Analyzer analyzer = new MyStandardAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig indexAnalyzer = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
    IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath).toPath()), indexAnalyzer);

    File file = new File(filePath1);
    Document document = new Document();

    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
        StringField stringField = new StringField("field", line, Field.Store.YES);
        document.add(stringField);  
    }
    indexWriter.addDocument(document);
    br.close();
    indexWriter.close();
}

public static void searchIndex(String searchString) throws IOException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("Searching for '" + searchString + "'");

    IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath).toPath())));

    FuzzyQuery myFuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term(searchString, "field"),2);
    try{
        TopDocs top = indexSearcher.search(myFuzzyQuery,100);
        System.out.println("Number of hits in TopDoc array: " + top.totalHits);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Oops");
    }

}
```

}

This code returns 0 hits. (While searching a text file that should have multiple hits, some matching exactly.)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have the arguments to your `Term` backward.  Should be:

```
FuzzyQuery myFuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field", searchString),2);
```

Second, Since you are using `StandardAnalyzer` (or something like it), all of your content in the index is lowercased.

Your query, however, won't be run through the analyzer.  If you want to apply analysis to the query, you can use a queryparser (note: fuzzy queries aren't actually analyzed, but it *will* take care of the lowercasing for you):

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("field", new MyStandardAnalyzer());
Query parsedQuery = parser.parse(searchString + "~");
```

Otherwise, you may just need to lowercase the terms yourself:

```
FuzzyQuery myFuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field", searchString.toLowerCase()),2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've reversed the arguments in my Term and now I'm getting one match/hit where I should be getting multiple---going to look into that now.

Aside from the flipped arguments in Term, I took the standard analyzer and remove the lowercase filter, as I needed it to be case sensitive.
In the end, I went a different route to finding a solution for the problem,  but I'd still like to get a handle on this for future use.